# TRIM function in query not working

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to query a log using the following:

```
select title, count(log.path) as views 
from articles join log on articles.slug = trim(leading '/article/' from path) 
group by articles.title order by views desc;
```

However, I am only receiving 6 results back.  Below is the 8 that I should be receiving back.

table below is for log.path:

```
/article/candidate-is-jerk
/article/media-obsessed-with-bears
/article/goats-eat-googles
/article/balloon-goons-doomed
/article/bears-love-berries
/article/trouble-for-troubled
/article/bad-things-gone
/article/so-many-bears
```

table for articles:

### slug

bad-things-gone

balloon-goons-doomed

bears-love-berries

candidate-is-jerk

goats-eat-googles

media-obsessed-with-bears

trouble-for-troubled

so-many-bears

Shouldn't my query work because I am trimming `'/article/'` from the file path?

I know I can use `substring(log.path FROM 10)` in place of `trim(leading '/article/' from path)` to get the result that I want, but I believe my query should work too.  Can anyone give me insight as to why my query isn't working?

Also, I'm trying this bit of code:

```
 select title, count(log.path) as views from articles, log where log.path like 
'%/articles.slug' group by articles.title order by views desc;
```

which is giving me 0 rows.  Can anyone help?

Comment: The query returns `title`, you're comparing `slug` and `path`. It's hard to tell what it's supposed to return without seeing the original table data.

Comment: Is it possible that some `path` values have leading spaces?

Comment: @Barmar could be right. The usual suspect with trim functions misbehaving is bad data. Try to just select the records using where path like '/article/%' see if you get the same 6. then its not the trim function.

Comment: added slug and path tables.  tried  '/article/%' and its still only giving me 6 out of the 8

Comment: update.  I was talking with some people and realized this might be a bug.  based on the examples on different websites, it should work, but it doesn't.  On the other hand, I did find 3 other ways of solving the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to join tables with this condition *TRIM(articles.slug) = TRIM(TRIM(leading '/article/' from path))*